# laravel using foreign keys

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I just cant see this
I have events, users, items tables

```
events
_______________________
id | name

users
______________________
id | name

items
_______________________
id | event_id  | user_id. | name
```

I want items deleted when either an event or user are deleted

```
Schema::table('items', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
Schema::table('items', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('events_id')->references('id')->on('events');
    });
```

So if I add **->onDelete('cascade')** to both when the user or event are deleted the item will be also deleted?

Comment: What prevents you from trying it yourself?

Answer (score 2):

> So if I add **->onDelete('cascade')** to both when the user or event are
>   deleted the item will be also deleted?

That's correct.

When you delete a row from the `users` table, all rows in the `items` table with the same `user_id` will be deleted.

When you delete a row from the `events` table, all rows in the `items` table with the same `event_id` will be deleted.